# Is the simulators viewpoint still valid?

Tags: llm, hallucination, terminology, transformers

When considering the behavior of large language models, there is not yet a single canonical framework for interpreting their output in context. Common proposed frameworks include:

- Agents: The LLM implements an agentive mind with volition and desires.
- Oracle: The LLM implements a librarian who conducts [reference interviews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_interview).
- Genie: The LLM implements an expert synthesizer of constructions.
- Tool: The LLM is a general-purpose text transformer.

The [simulators viewpoint](https://generative.ink/posts/simulators/) subsumes all of these by claiming that LLMs implement *simulations* of various conversations: simulating conversations between agents, between librarians and patrons, between builders and designers, or even simulating the behavior of a hypothetical text-transforming tool.

There are many attractive features of the simulators viewpoint, but it is also falsifiable. **Is the simulators viewpoint still valid?** Or has it been refuted or made obsolete?

Comment: i think the frameworks proposed by the article you linked is non-standard and mostly exists as a series of strawmen in order to reach the synthesis of the "simulator viewpoint". I don't think any of these 5 is a good way to think about LLMs, including simulators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably still valid. LLM stands for large language model -- it models its training data by predicting the next (or any masked) tokens given the context.

I tend to be a bigger fan of the "simulators" analogy as e.g., thinking about LLMs as "agents" tends to add too much anthropomorphism which clouds my intuition regarding these models.

Additionally, it still holds true that LLMs are trained on vast amounts of heterogenous data, meaning that it simultaneously models a plethora of types and styles of text.

However, such models are additionally instruction-tuned on conversational data, allowing the user to interact with the model in a more chat-bot-style way. It *could* be that, with this instruction-tuning, such models can no longer adequately model the diverse styles of text-data found in its pretraining dataset. It would depend on the diversity of model generations.

At least with Llama 2, you can manipulate the style of the assistant-style responses with a system prompt, suggesting that that method of instruction-tuning still allows for some variation in text-completions to be kept.